# Do any coffee chains do real mochas?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso

When I make a mocha for myself at home I make a hot chocolate with *real* cocoa and then add a double espresso (made using a [Bialetti Venus](http://www.bialetti.com/www.bialetti.com/coffee/stovetop/stainless-pots-c-1_7_21.html)). Every coffee I have had at popular coffee shop chains use "mocha syrup", an over-sweet, artificial tasting mass-produced alternative. Does anyone know any coffee chains that make a mocha using real cocoa?

Comment: It's quite subjective what a mocha is. I've heard that what you're talking about is a café viennois, not a mocha.  I'm flagging this as opinion based for that reason.

Comment: Perhaps the operative phrase here is "coffee shop *chain*"! Seek out a local, boutique coffee shop or restaurant that caters to traditionally-prepared, high-quality, low-volume business. This is no doubt difficult to find, especially depending on your area. Drinks based on syrup or pre-mix is no doubt easier to prepare and tasty (-enough) to the masses. Go local!

Comment: @hoc_age Unfortunately I live in the middle of nowhere so when I'm in town (very rarely) I like sitting down for a coffee but don't really have time to search around for an independent coffee shop, that's if there actually is one! The nearest city is 50 miles away so that's also how far away the "local" boutique coffee shops are :(

Comment: Starbucks's mocha sauce is cocoa powder, sugar, vanillin, hot water and elbow grease. The vanilla is artificial, but the cocoa is real.